# how to find much matches of one objects from one queryset in another queryset Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

how to find many matches with one object from the set of queryset objects (which contain one search object) in another many queryset django objects

for example, how to find the most frequent product in order products and deduce its quantity

> I apologize for such a question, I'm still noob and my brains can not
>   so critical think

order models

```
class Order(models.Model):                  
    products_of_order = models.ManyToManyField("ProducInOrder", related_name='Some_Products')

class ProducInOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, default=None)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

product models

```
class Product(models.Model):
        name_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

i try to do this:

```
 product = Product.objects.all()
 some  = Order.objects.filter(products_of_order__product__in=product).count()
```

but it's just return all product which contain in order products,
how to get count each product in orders products which matches with list of products.

i have one idea how to make it but i wanna make it in one line) in one queryset)

```
some_dict = {}
for i in some:
    for s in i.products_of_order.all():
        if s.product.name_of_product in some_dict:
            some_dict.s.product.name_of_product += 1
        else:
            some_dict.s.product.name_of_product = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking. But that last piece of code would be expressed more naturally using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
count = collections.defaultdict(int)
for order in some:
    for product in order.products_of_order.all():
        count[product.name] += 1
```